# How to filter out unwanted tags within tags

Tags: python, tags, beautifulsoup

I am trying to pull a bulleted list from this page here: http://bodetree.com/what-is-causing-your-headaches-startup-pain-points/

Specifically, the bullets highlighted in yellow in the screenshot below.

[image]

First, I use beautiful soup to filter out all `<ul>` tags that don't have attributes:

```js
text = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://bodetree.com/what-is-causing-your-headaches-startup-pain-points/', timeout=7.00).text)
bullets = text.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'ul' and not tag.attrs)
```

Here are two of the `<ul>` tags that are returned:

```html
<ul>
<li>You are experiencing a decrease in sales and customers</li>
<li>If your brand design does not reflect what you deliver</li>
<li>If you want to attract a new target audience</li>
<li>Management change</li>
<li><a href="http://www.risingabovethenoise.com/how-to-rebrand-19-questions-ask-before-you-start/" onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'outbound-article', 'http://www.risingabovethenoise.com/how-to-rebrand-19-questions-ask-before-you-start/', '19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding');">19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding</a></li>
</ul>

<ul><li class="share-item share-fb" data-title="What is Causing your Headaches?- Startup Pain Points" data-type="facebook" data-url="http://bodetree.com/what-is-causing-your-headaches-startup-pain-points/" title="Facebook"></li><li class="share-item share-tw" data-title="What is Causing your Headaches?- Startup Pain Points" data-type="twitter" data-url="http://bodetree.com/what-is-causing-your-headaches-startup-pain-points/" title="Twitter"></li><li class="share-item share-gp" data-lang="en-US" data-title="What is Causing your Headaches?- Startup Pain Points" data-type="googlePlus" data-url="http://bodetree.com/what-is-causing-your-headaches-startup-pain-points/" title="Google+"></li><li class="share-item share-pn" data-media="http://bodetree.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/pain-points.png" data-title="What is Causing your Headaches?- Startup Pain Points" data-type="pinterest" data-url="http://bodetree.com/what-is-causing-your-headaches-startup-pain-points/" title="Pinterest"></li></ul>
```

I only want to pull the `<ul>` tags which occur in the body of the page, so I'd want to filter out that second `<ul>` tag with the junk in it. It appears that the `<ul>` tags that don't occur in the body of the page have `<li>` tags with attributes in them so we can filter based on that. Basically all I want is a tag structure of the form `<ul><li>string</li></ul>`. So in this case, the only `<ul>` I want returned is :

```html
<ul> 
<li>You are experiencing a decrease in sales and customers</li> 
<li>If your brand design does not reflect what you deliver</li> 
<li>If you want to attract a new target audience</li> 
<li>Management change</li> 
<li>19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do this with find_all()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the `ul` inside the article, which is a `div` with `class="entry-content"`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://bodetree.com/what-is-causing-your-headaches-startup-pain-points/', timeout=7.00).text)

bullets = soup.select("div.entry-content ul li")
print([bullet.get_text() for bullet in bullets])
```

Prints:

```
[
    'You are experiencing a decrease in sales and customers', 
    'If your brand design does not reflect what you deliver', 
    'If you want to attract a new target audience', 
    'Management change', 
    '19 Questions to Ask Yourself Before You Start Rebranding'
]
```

Comment: I'd like to incorporate the paragraph preceding the <ul> as well to lend context. And I want it all to be one string. So I do bullets = text.select("div.entry-content ul") and then uls_with_ps = [(ul.findPrevious('p'), ul) for ul in bullets] and print [j.get_text() for j in uls_with_ps], though I get an error saying "'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_text'". Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: @MikaSchiller to get the preceding paragraph, locate the `ul` element and use `find_previous_sibling("p")` to get the preceding paragraph. To make it all one string use `join()`, for example: `" ".join([bullet.get_text() for bullet in bullets])`.